# how to interface camera preview stream from android to Qt5?

Tags: android, qt, interface, camera, preview

Who knows how to interface camera preview stream data from android to Qt5?
I Want to display preview stream on Qt. and then I'll send the reformat stream to android.
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using [QCamera](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcamera.html#setViewfinder-3), then you can set custom ViewFinder( class derived from [QAbstractVideoSurface](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qabstractvideosurface.html) ) to QCamera.

```
void QCamera::setViewfinder(QAbstractVideoSurface * surface)
```

And then when stream is available,view finder's present method will get called with VideoFrame, from where you can get image data and do whatever you want.

```
bool QAbstractVideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame & frame)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tested Qcamera example in multimediawidgets Qt5.2, but not previewing, I confirmed it on Qt bug list, Qt site. Are you talking another way? How about interface java?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, to me it looks like you want to manipulate the camera video stream. what i suggested is for the same.